# angularJS assigning a variable within a controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller bringing in the contents of a json file:

```
function phoneListController($scope, $http) {
 $http.get('phones.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.phones = data.offers_basic_data;
    $scope.features = data.equipmentSearchFeatures;
 }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log('error');
 });
}
```

This works great, however I need to use one of the items in the phones scope (product id) to grab the correct features in the second scope. Do I place something like:

```
var productid = phones.1.productid;
```

within the function? On the page? I'm using "ng-data-repeat" to list out the phones, would I put the variable within the repeat somehow? I tried a variety of ways to interject the product id {{phone.1.ProductID}} into the features scope: {{features.productID.0}} but nothing I do there seems to work. Any ideas/suggestions?

And please correct me if I'm using the incorrect terminology, I've been using angularJS less than a week!

---

I attempted to assign a variable within the function but it didn't work:

```
var productid = phones[1]['productID'];
```

And here's how I called it within the HTML:

```
Test: {{features.productid.0}}
```

---

Okay I'm really close, I know I'm missing something really stupid/little:

```
$scope.phones = data.offers_basic_data;
console.log(JSON.stringify(phones));
var productid = $scope.phones[1]['ProductID'];
$scope.features = data.equipmentSearchFeatures['Features'][productid];
```

The above does not work, but the phones are being listed on the page again instead of white nothing. I feel that I'm not incorporating the variable correctly into the array.

---

Here's a shot of the second array:

```
[equipmentSearchFeatures] => Array
    (
        [Features] => Array
            (
                [12312] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Test - no
```

---

Next tried using this line instead, still displays the phones, but not the test feature:

```
$scope.features = data.equipmentSearchFeatures['Features'][$scope.phones[1]['ProductID']];
```

Comment: Array indexing in Javascript should be used as `arr[5]`; `arr.5` is not valid syntax.

Comment: That was part of my question, I know how to call the value with the double curly brackets, but I wasn't sure how to correctly assign it within the function (or if that's even where I assign the value). Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: A little more context of what you are trying to do would probably help in guiding toward an answer.

Comment: See my last edit. I need a value from the first scope to get the proper values from the second scope. I'm realizing this is probably more of a JavaScript question than AngularJS.

Comment: @cfox: as wrote in my answer, I think you want to read **$scope.phones** instead of **phones**.

Comment: So the *name* of the array is the productId?  That seems odd.  Maybe do a console.log of the whole structure and post the output?

Comment: Yes, the name of the array is the productID. Right now I'm thinking I would be better served spending time structuring the json file rather than trying to work with how our CMS automatically spits things out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by reformatting the significantly reformatting the json file moving the features directly under the product and not a separate array. I'm sure there was a way to solve this using AngularJS, but less than a week in I'm just not able to figure out that solution.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edit, and assuming the property name is ProductID:

```
var productid = $scope.phones[1].ProductID;
```

**Edit**

Ok, I think I understand--`data.equipmentSearchFeatures` has a property called Features that is an array, and the members of the array have a property called productId, and you want to find the one that matches your variable productId?

You will need a loop for this.  This is not syntax checked, but should be close:

```
var productid = $scope.phones[1].ProductID; //get the product id

//loop over the Features collection until you match the productId
angular.forEach(data.equipmentSearchFeatures.Features, function(feature){
  if (feature.productId == productId){
    //now set the scope variable to the matching item
    $scope.features = feature;
  }
};
```

Comment: That did not change the output, still displaying the phones but not the test feature.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were just trying to get the productId.  Can you explain a bit more about the features structure?

Comment: Just another section of the json file located after "offers_basic_data". You can see from the second scope how it's structured, I just need to attach the product id from the first scope to pull the features for that product.

Comment: @PhilSandler: maybe *phones[1].productID;*? (**p** not **P** )

Comment: @Lame-up-duck: That's not the reason this isn't working - do you have a suggestion?

Comment: As per the edit, here's the structure of the array: [equipmentSearchFeatures][Features][123123][0] - Second to last number being the productID. Adding that code in and commenting out the other line declaring the second scope caused all phones to disappear.

Comment: Wait, so there is no property called productId, the property name is the number itself?

Comment: I updated my answer--I was missing the $scope in front of the work "phones".

Answer (score 0):

@cfox: try this:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(phones));
```

and see if you are looking for right elements!

But I think you want to do

```
var productid = $scope.phones[1].ProductID;
```

instead!

Comment: Didn't work. Console says it cannot ready the property of the variable productid. It looks like it's failing to get the productid declaring it this way within the function. Should I have it in a separate function or on the HTML page somewhere?

Comment: @cfox: *console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.phones))* didn't helped?

Comment: No that didn't result in any changes.